# get dynamic var from external javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have an external file that renders a video on my site using a dynamic URL with a token and an expire date. It looks like this:

```
https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/231231/
```

I add it to my page this way:

```
$vid = 231231; 
$url = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/") 
echo $url ;
```

And it then renders the javascript bellow and also some html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sources = [
                    {
                type:"video/mp4",
                src:"https://cdn.myvenue.com/media/clips/491355/clip_saple_hd.mp4?expire=1525179619&token=1e52da03af581764724c0e2c428a9faa",
                res:"VideoSample",
                label: "VideoSample"
            }
                        ];
    videojs("video", {
                        nativeControlsForTouch: true,
                                    autoplay: false,
                                    controls: true,
                        width:'100%',
            fluid: true,
                        loop: false,
                                    muted: false,
                                    poster: "https://cdn.static.myvenue.com/media/assets/images/image.jpg",

     etc., etc., etc.
```

The problem is that I just need to get the video URL (remember: it's dynamic):

```
https://cdn.myvenue.com/media/clips/491355/clip_saple_hd.mp4?expire=1525179619&token=1e52da03af581764724c0e2c428a9faa
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'renders'? Do you mean that the `www.thevideositeurl.com ` url  returns a string with the this script (including the `<script>` tags), or do you mean that when you add the url in a script tag that is adds this script to the page?

Comment: script of this type have a `textContent` attribute. can you use that?

Comment: @Mark_M it returns a string with the this script (including the <script> tags)

Comment: @Mark_M I have updated my question. Can you please see if it helps?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get to the first object (or maybe you only have one) in your `sources` array you can get the video url like this;

```
var videoURL = sources[0].src;
```

> Update // for PHP code, based on a modified version of @Moti's regex

```
echo $url;
preg_match('/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^\"]*/', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$videoURL = ($matches[0][0]);
echo $videoURL;
```

Comment: Can you pelase elabororate this?

Comment: How do you include the "dynamic URL" on your site (or page)?

Comment: this way: `$vid = 231231;
$url = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/") echo $url ;` I then renders the javascript mentione and also some html

Comment: Are you using PHP on server side? Where do you need the `video URL`, on the server side or on the client side?

Comment: I need it on the server side

Comment: Then @Moti answered your question, but since you `echo $url ;` I would give to the `video URL` another name like `$videoURL = preg_match ("/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^\"]*/",$url)[0];`

Comment: The @Moti solution is giving me a sintax error on this line `$url = preg_match ("/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^\"]*/",$url)[0]` Could you know if this might be caused by my php version?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the returned text in a variable name `scriptSrc` This code will give you the url

```js
const scriptSrc = `<script type="text/javascript">
var sources = [
            {
            type:"video/mp4",
            src:"https://cdn.myvenue.com/media/clips/491355/clip_saple_hd.mp4?expire=1525179619&token=1e52da03af581764724c0e2c428a9faa",
            res:"VideoSample",
            label: "VideoSample"
            }...`
const url = scriptSrc.match(/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^"]*/)
console.log(url)
```

Edit: in PHP you can match with the same regex like this

```
$url = file_get_contents("https://www.thevideositeurl.com/embed/{$vid}/")
preg_match('/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^\"]*/', $url, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$videoURL = ($matches[0][0]);
echo $videoURL;
```

Comment: This is giving me a sintax error on this line `$url = preg_match ("/https:\/\/cdn\.myvenue\.com\/[^\"]*/",$url)[0]` Can this be caused by my php version?

Comment: I'm also accepting this because I believe it may work. Thanks!